# Computing $\lim_{x\to (3/2)^-} (x^2+1)/(3x-2x^2)$

Tags: limits, infinity

I am trying to compute
$$\large \lim_{x\to \frac32^-}\frac{x^2+1}{3x-2x^2}$$

I know the numerator will equal one fine and how it becomes $x^2+1 * 1/(3x-2x^2)$ because $a/b = a * 1/b$, but then I'm not sure where I go from there, I know the answer is positive infinity but once I get $1/3x-2x^2$ I try to plug $3/2$ in and that gets $0$, I then plugin slightly over or under $3/2$ like $1.6$ or $1.4$ and I get valid outputs. I had the same problem earlier except it approached 0 from the left side and it was negative infinity, I have absolutely no idea what to do or where to go from this.

Comment: Do you mean $$\lim_{x\to 3/2}-\frac{x^2+1}{3-2x^2}$$?

Comment: Yeah the x still needs to stay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Note that

$$3x-2x^2=2x\left(\frac32-x\right)$$

Comment: I'm confused  on how I would use that , shouldn't all instances of x be 3/2? Not just the first one in the parenthesis

Comment: What are the sign for $2x$ and $(3/2-x)$ as  $x\to \frac32^-$ that is $x=\frac32-\epsilon$ with $\epsilon>0$ "small".

Comment: (2(3/2))/(3/2-3/2)?? I know its zero but where does it being negative infinity come? Versus it being positive infinity

Comment: @oso9817 Recall that $x$ is never exactly equal to $\frac32$ but something smaller than that.

Comment: so it would be anything less than 3/2? Either way even when I substitute 1.4 I get 0 again so I'm confused. I'm not sure if I'm understanding the concept

Comment: @oso9817 Let assume for example $x=\frac{30}{21}$, what is the sign of $\frac32-\frac{30}{21}$?

Comment: @oso9817 You need to recall the definition of limit. Not ethat  $x\to \frac32^-$ means that $x$ approches the value $\frac32$ "from the left" of the real line that is with values less that $\frac32$ therefore what is the sign of $(3/2-x)$?

Comment: Ok I think I’m getting it. Was your first step of factoring it out mandatory?

Comment: @oso9817 Well it is a good way in that case to see what is the sign for the denominator. Since it is polynomial and 3/2 is a root it is possible to factorize that, then that's method is recommended here. As an laternative we can derive $f(x)=3x-2x^2 \implies f'(x)=3-4x$ and note that $f'(3/2)=3-6=-3<0$ therefore the function is decreasing in a neighborhood of $x=3/2$, but it is a more complicated way.

Comment: Wait can you explain again the difference it makes? I’m doing it right now on paper and it’s positive if 2x(3/2-1) that would be 1 aka positive. It’s on the left side of 3/2 too

Comment: Ok I think I understand it now. Disregard the last comment of mine I accidentally read my problem as approaching from the right. Following your function 2x(3/2-x) and substituting -1.6 would make it negative while still being on the left side of 3/2 E: never mind on that forgot the double negatives.

Comment: @oso9817 Yes of course, but since we are considering the limit as $x \to \frac32^-$ what matters here is the sign in a left neighborhood of $\frac32$.

Comment: So everything less than 3/2 ? So it seems everything thay isn’t negative or not more than 3/2 would be valid. I don’t see how that results in positive infinity

Comment: Seems to be like 0<x<3/2 not infinity

Comment: @oso9817 Note that $x$ is approaching $3/2$ for values less than $3/2$. Then the factor $2x$ is positive and also the factor (3/2-x) is positive since $x<3/2$. Note that it is true for all values $0<x<3/2$ and therefore it is true for any left neighborhood of $3/2$ contained in that interval,

Comment: Why does it have to be more than 0 and less than 3/2. Because of that and how it is able to get “infinitely” closer to 3/2 with things like 1.499999999 is that where the infinity label comes in? I still don’t see why you don’t plug-in -1.6 in 2(-1.6)(3/2+1.6) because that seems to me to disprove it being positive infinity because it would turn into -3.2*3.1 which is a negative all the while being on the left

Comment: The value at $x=-1.6$ is not relevant for the limit, indeed we are interested to the value of the function when x is closer and closer to 3/2 but less than that value, that is  for example $x=1.49999999...$. Since the value of the function becomes arbitrarily large when x get closer and closer to 3/2 “from the left” we say, according to the definition, that the limit is $+\infty$ or that the function diverges to positive infinity.

Comment: Ok I see now. I think at least. So if it’s coming from the left you want to put it slightly under what it’s approaching? What would have happened if we plugged thay in from the start

Comment: @oso9817 Yes exactly! What do you men with " What would have happened if we plugged thay in from the start?"

Comment: @oso9817 Sorry but I don't understand, what do you mean with "If we just plugged the $3x-2x^2$"? The sentence seems incomplete.

Comment: 1.499999, what was the point in all the other steps since because factoring out doesn’t change the core function does it ?

Comment: @oso9817 Yes we can plug is some numerical values as 1.49999 and see what happens but it is not a rigorous way to proceed. Otherwise by factorization we see that $2x(3/2-x) \to 0$ and $2x(3/2-x) >0$ as $x \to \frac32^-$ therefore we have a positive finite numerator divided by an arbitrary small positive number and the limit is $+\infty$.

Comment: Ok I’m pretty sure I have the hang of this. Do you do anything with the numerator?

Comment: @oso9817 The numerator approces $13/4$ therefore it is positive when x approches 3/2.

Answer (score 1):

For such a problem, let $x=y+\frac 32$ to make
$$ \lim_{x\to \frac32}\frac{x^2+1}{3x-2x^2}=-\lim_{y\to0}\frac{13+12y+4 y^2}{12y+8 y^2}=-\lim_{y\to0}\frac{13+12y+4 y^2}{12y(1+\frac 23 y)}$$ Since $y$ is small, the numerator is almost $13$ and the denominator almost $12y$.

Answer (score 1):

Graphical way to observe the denominator $3x-2x^2$:

$\hspace{3cm}$[image: ![enter image description here]

It implies that as $x\to 1.5$, $3x-2x^2\to 0+$.

Hence:
$$\lim_{x\to \frac32-}\frac{x^2+1}{3x-2x^2}=\frac{13/4}{0+}=+\infty.$$

Answer (score 0):

The numerator will not equal $1$, it will approach $1+(\frac 32)^2=\frac {13}{4}$.  The denominator will approach $0$ but always be positive because $x \lt \frac 32$.  The ratio will therefore go to $+\infty$.  A graph is below.  The fact that $x$ approaches from below means you are on the lower piece of the graph, which goes to $+\infty$[image]

Comment: The OP knows the answer is $+\infty$, the problem here is to find a good and simple method to prove that. The plot is very clear but I suppose the OP is looking for something based on alebraic or precalculus considerations. That' only my opinion of course.

Comment: Correct. I’m looking to solve this analytically without a graph or calculator

Comment: I couldn't understand what you were really looking for.  I would just determine that the numerator and denominator are positive and the denominator goes to zero to determine the fact that the limit is $+\infty$.  I put the graph in to explain what is going on.

Comment: How do you get the denominator to be positive? If x<3/2 wouldn’t thay mean it would also reach the negatives

Comment: When the denominator is close to $\frac 32$ but below, the $3x$ term is more positive than the $-2x^2$ is negative, so the sum is positive.  Just compute it for $1.49$, for example.  When you are taking a limit you are working close to the point, so don't have to worry about the fact that $3x-2x^2$ gets negative if $x$ is large and negative.